# get a specific variable from a queryset

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a specific part of the `cd` output, but my code is not working. I'm trying to define a new variable, with only the object 'symbols' from the Queryset output.

```
        if cmd_exec == '/wanalysis':
            get_Memory = Memory.objects.filter(user=current_user).values() 
            cd = get_Memory.all()  
            X = cd['{id}']
            print(X)
```

This is the output for `print(cd)`

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 183, 'user_id': 1, 'raw_message': '/setworkspace AAPL TSLA MSFT 12/12/2018 12/12/2022', 'date1': '2018-12-12', 'date2': '2022-12-12', 'symbols': "['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'MSFT']"}]>
```

I would like to define a variable X, with the 'symbols' output from the QuerySet.

So something like:

```
X = cd['symbols']
```

Answer (score 0):

The QuerySet contains a list of dictionaries.

If you are certain there is only one `Memory` for each user, you can do the following to retrieve only that `Memory` instance:

```
if cmd_exec == '/wanalysis':
        get_Memory = Memory.objects.filter(user=current_user).values() 
        cd = get_Memory.first()
        X = cd['symbols']
        print(X)
```

If there can be more than one `Memory` per user, you need to construct a list of symbols by iterating over the queryset:

```
if cmd_exec == '/wanalysis':
        get_Memory = Memory.objects.filter(user=current_user).values() 
        cd = get_Memory.all()  
        X = [memory['symbol'] for memory in cd]
        print(X)
```

Is there a reason you are retrieving values() instead of the model objects?